# why AutoCompleteTextView is not working

Tags: android

`AutoCompleteTextView` is not working. I am a beginner of Android. I have no error in the emulator

My code is given below

#### MainActivity

```
package com.example.stackflow_test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView act;
    String[] country={"France ","USA","Bangladesh","Canada","Other"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    
    EditText et1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), et1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //et1.setEnabled(false);
        
        
        
        act=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
                
        
    }

    


}
```

Comment: `...---...` - ... lucky us, you can't write your code in Morse!

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? "Not working" is too vague for us to be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this step........

```
act.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I know the question didn't have much detail but you should still but at least a *little* detail in your answer so others understand better *why* they should "try this step".